# wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly... i want to work with debug on

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, debug

**i know that this error is just a notice:**

```
notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. please see debugging in wordpress for more information. (this message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/linksfrkses/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3547
```

**But, on many project i want to work with the debug on.**
once i even solved this - but, i cant remember how...

i searched and checked and keep getting posts saying
"use wp_enqueue_scripts" but i am...
So, what is wrong with this code:

```
    function enqueue_stuff(){

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcss', 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), false);
    wp_enqueue_style('maincss', BASE_URL . '/css/main.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), 3.3, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('chainedjs', BASE_URL.'/js/jquery.chained.mini.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('miscscripts', BASE_URL.'/js/misc-scripts.js', array('jquery'), false, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stuff');
```

Comment: That notice is thrown when `wp_enqueue_script()` is used inside an early hook e.g. when used directly in `functions.php` without be wrapped in a hook. But in your code above it is used properly, on `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` hook, so problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: do you mean a plugin? (based on that question) any way to trace the source? the error / notice message is pretty general.

Comment: search your `wp-content` directory for instances of `wp_enqueue_script`, it's elsewhere in your theme, or a plugin.

Comment: thats a good way to go about it. thanks a lot for helping mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... after @milo comments i went ahead and searched for
wp_enqueue_scripts in my plugin folders and found 2 plugins doing it wrong.

Fixed them (until the next update) and everything works...
So, i have no controll - these are good plugins and yet.
wrote the plugins authors and hope for the best.

thats all - case solved